# im trying to use diagram.highlightCollection in gojs to highlight nodes that fail certain condition

Tags: javascript, gojs

i am having id of nodes (key) , i want to highlight those node, for empty node the same condition works fine. ex :

```
    checkEmptyNodes() {
           const emptyNodes = [];
           const diagDetails =  this.myserv.getDiagramData();
           if (!!diagDetails.nodeDataArray) {
           diagram.startTransaction('checking empty nodes');
           diagram.nodes.each(n => {
                       if (!n.part.data.answer) {
                           emptyNodes.push(n);
                   }
           });
           diagram.highlightCollection(emptyNodes);
           console.log(emptyNodes);
          }   else {
           // data.answer = [];
          }
           diagram.commitTransaction('checking empty nodes');
           return emptyNodes;
         }
```

the above code works but i have a similar code which is not giving any error but nodes are not getting highlighted

```
          changeNodeColor(broken){
            const brokenNodes = [];
            diagram.nodes.each(n => {
                     if (broken.includes(n.Zd.key)) {
                     diagram.startTransaction('checking hanging nodes');
                    brokenNodes.push(n);
                         }
                     });
                 console.log("data here nk data");
                 console.log(brokenNodes);
                 diagram.highlightCollection(brokenNodes);
                 diagram.commitTransaction('checking hanging nodes');
                 return brokenNodes;
              }
```

i have really no clue how the previous one work and why the second work does not .
any gojs expert.

Answer (score 0):

I have already answered this question at https://forum.nwoods.com/t/i-want-to-color-node-based-on-certain-condition/13169  For completeness here, this was my answer:

Don’t use `Zd`. That’s a minified property name, and it is repeatedly stated in the documentation and in this forum that you should not use those internal names. Use only documented API property and method names: https://gojs.net/api.

Why are you calling **startTransaction** inside an iteration or loop? You didn’t before. There should always be a pairing of calls to **startTransaction** and **commitTransaction** (or **rollbackTransaction**). Those pairings are normally sequential, but they may nest.